# SQLite LIKE statement doesn´t find a match when it should

Tags: python, sqlite

I have some piece of code in Python 3 to retrieve an id. The column of the LIKE statement are 18 rows with the following text.

"Tercera División G 1" from number 1 to number 18.

My matching code is as follows:

```
    lig=liga[0]
    print('lig',lig)
    cur.execute('''SELECT id FROM Campeonato WHERE id_pais=? AND nombre LIKE 
    ?''', (self.idp,'%'+lig+'%'))
    foo=cur.fetchall()
    print('foo',foo)
    if foo is None or len(foo)==0:
        return
    elif len(foo)>1:
        if len(liga)>1: lig2=' '+liga[-1]
        print('buscador','%'+lig+'%'+lig2)
        cur.execute('''SELECT id FROM Campeonato WHERE id_pais=? AND nombre 
        LIKE ?''',(self.idp,'%'+lig+'%'+lig2))
        foo=cur.fetchall()
        print('foofinal',foo)
        if len(foo)>1:
            if len(liga)>2:
                lig=' '.join(liga[0:2])
                cur.execute('''SELECT id FROM Campeonato WHERE id_pais=? AND 
                name LIKE ?''',(self.idp,'%'+lig+'%'+lig2))
                foo=cur.fetchall()
                if len(foo)!=1:
                    print('Revisar partido. No se encuentra la liga entre 
                    varias opciones')                 
                    return
                else:
                    id_competicion=foo[0][0]

        elif len(foo)==0:
            print('Revisar partido, no se encuentra la liga')                
            return
        else:
            id_competicion=foo[0][0]
    elif len(foo)==1:
        id_competicion=foo[0][0]
    else:
        id_competicion=None
    cur.close()
```

So, to put it simple. First you search "Tercera" with LIKE and it returns abunch of results, all 18 of them. Then you search "Tercera+whatever+space+number" and that should return just one result and exit the loop.

Liga variable is from BSoup, and in the end, all 18 queries are as follow:

```
First look for %Tercera% and retrieve 18 results

Then look for %Tercera% 2 or whichever of the 18 numbers
```

The thing is. Everything is successful in all but one. When it has to search %Tercera% 3 it doesn´t match anything, and "Tercera División G 3" IS in the database.

I mean the is no other difference to explain why it only happens with the number 3, and I don't even know what to look for.

Any ideas why it is going this way?

Comment: Please include your database scheme or some example of your table

Comment: Is there white space after the 3?

Answer (score 0):

All right I finally got what was happening. I´m looking for %Tercera% 3 which means that the matching text must end with: " 3". The problem, looking one by one again in DB Browser is that while all others had 20 characters, this row had 21, being the last one a newline.
Had my search been %Tercera% 3% it would have been fine.

So, I consider it solved. If you like to remove the post, or leave it just in case someone has a similar problem and use it to point where to look at is up to you.

Thanks anyway

Comment: I think this is an appropriate Q/A pair. Might not receive tons of upvotes, but there is no need to delete. You might consider editing the question and title, to make it more useful and findable for others. Keep it without the knowledge of the solution, i.e. ask as if you did not know. But make it shorter, more like an [mcve]. That way, some upvotes might be in for you.

Comment: You might want to take the [tour], it makes your profile nicer (and there are some users who donvote just because the badge is missing...).